# How to pull out an exception context record when the exception processing caused a crash

Tags: c++, windows, exception, windbg, stack-trace

I have an issue tracking down a crash within my application using windbg.  Usually I get a dump file for this application in a specified location and can debug the issue easily.  It seems that this time the application crashed while it was writing out the details of the exception to a dump file.  I managed to pull out the system mdmp and hdmp files using the event log to identify the file locations and have looked at the hdmp file.  The context record for the exception seems to be the processing of the exception and not the primary exception that caused the issue in the first place.  Is there any way I can trace back from this information to pull out the context of the original exception that caused the crash?  I really need to see the stack trace of the thread at the time the exception was thrown to help identify the core problem.

------------------------------------Context of program -----------------------------------

```
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00000000`77983072 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
00000000`779832b5 : 00000000`0000122c 00000000`00001240 00000000`7eccecd0 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx+0x1d2
00000000`7798331a : 00000000`c0000374 00000000`7eccecb0 00000000`7eccecb0 ffffffff`ee1e5d00 : ntdll!RtlReportException+0xb5
00000000`77984155 : 00000000`77984102 00000000`778e9b6e 00000000`00000000 000007fe`00000000 : ntdll!RtlpTerminateFailureFilter+0x1a
00000000`778d85c8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`779dd700 00000000`779f7350 : ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x96
00000000`778e9d2d : 00000000`7ecd0000 00000000`7eccecb0 00000000`7eccecb0 00000000`77a0ee9c : ntdll!_C_specific_handler+0x8c
00000000`778d91cf : 00000000`7ecd0000 00000000`00000048 00000000`00012f00 00000000`00250a90 : ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
00000000`778d97c8 : 00000000`7eccecd0 00000000`7ecce6a0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x45a
00000000`77984102 : 00000000`c0000374 00000000`00000000 00000000`779fb4b0 00000000`fffffff7 : ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0x22f
00000000`77984746 : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000023 00000000`7eccf0c0 00000000`00000003 : ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x62
00000000`77985952 : 00000000`846fb401 00000000`00000000 00000005`00000011 41b0d0a0`00000000 : ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+0x26
00000000`77987604 : 00000000`00fb0000 00000000`00fb0000 00000000`00000000 00000000`03d24a80 : ntdll!RtlpHeapHandleError+0x12
00000000`7792150b : 00000000`00fb0000 00000000`88062a40 00000000`88062c10 00000000`03d24a80 : ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+0xa4
00000000`779140fd : 00000000`00fb0000 000007fe`fd8c0001 00000000`88062a40 00000000`88062a50 : ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+0x1649
00000000`777c300a : ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`74b10f80 22739480`0007001a 000f0002`000707de : ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1a6
00000000`6c33cabc : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!HeapFree+0xa
00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`74b10f80 : msvcr90!free+0x1c
```

--The exception context record points to a handling of an exception and not to the location of the orginal exception.  Note that RtlRaiseException is not listed where the parameter might point to the location of the exception context that it was handling.--

```
rax=00000000068a285b rbx=00000000c0000374 rcx=000000007ecce6a0
rdx=00000000779fb4b0 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=00000000779fb4b0
rip=0000000077984102 rsp=000000007eccecb0 rbp=0000000000000002
r8=0ca97dc0e6ad047e  r9=00000000382a5066 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000286 r12=0000000000000003 r13=0000000088062a50
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x62:
00000000`77984102 eb00            jmp     ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x64 (00000000`77984104)
0:088> kb
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00000000`77984746 : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000023 00000000`7eccf0c0 00000000`00000003 : ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x62
00000000`77985952 : 00000000`846fb401 00000000`00000000 00000005`00000011 41b0d0a0`00000000 : ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+0x26
00000000`77987604 : 00000000`00fb0000 00000000`00fb0000 00000000`00000000 00000000`03d24a80 : ntdll!RtlpHeapHandleError+0x12
00000000`7792150b : 00000000`00fb0000 00000000`88062a40 00000000`88062c10 00000000`03d24a80 : ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+0xa4
00000000`779140fd : 00000000`00fb0000 000007fe`fd8c0001 00000000`88062a40 00000000`88062a50 : ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+0x1649
00000000`777c300a : ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`74b10f80 22739480`0007001a 000f0002`000707de : ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1a6
00000000`6c33cabc : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!HeapFree+0xa
00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`74b10f80 : msvcr90!free+0x1c
```

Some useful information is located at the following URL but it didn't help me find anything for this x64 bit process: http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=309

Comment: If you have heap corruption (possibly), you can enable page heap using gflags and then run the application with WinDbg attached and when it crashes, run `!analyze -v` it should give you sensible call stacks

Comment: Running the program again and trying the reproduce the bug is another process we are working on but I'm guessing that somewhere in this heap dump is information about the original crash.  There is no sure way to reproduce this crash without having some information about the crash since we can not produce the exact conditions that were experienced.

Comment: Does this help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/01/30/363428.aspx or this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/01/18/355697.aspx they detail how to recover the call stack from an exception

Comment: You found the exception context fine. The problem is that the context has a broken stack chain. You'll have to manually reconstruct the call stack starting at `msvcr90!free`.

Comment: It looks like I found the context of an exception. But it looks more like an exception is being thrown while it is processing the handling of an earlier exception.  I'm not sure that it is a broken stack chain as much as an exception during an exception but I will look at reconstructing stack chains.

Comment: Since kernel32!HeapFree+0xa is on the stack, you should do a !heap -s -v to check for heap corruption. On a large dump this will take a very long time

Comment: Based on your comment I have tried: .ecxr, dps @rsp, d, d, d ... to see beyond the original stack shown but I'm not completely sure that I'm seeing a real call stack.

Comment: The bug was reproduced with gflags turned on and that found the problem area.  A stack was reconstructed by others using an internal offset inside a structure.